# Run report based on a user's Sort on a Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have several reports that populate off the Form below. I would like to add a function for when a user uses the column `Sort` drop downs, the reports only look at the visible records.

So for example a report run while viewing the window below would return only files where the customer is named `Placeholder`.

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this with a macro or query without resorting to VBA?

Comment: I've tried filters, setting the report's control source equal to the form and queries, no luck so far.

Comment: You'll probably need VBA to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro ended up working well.

[image]